# Are traffic_signals always part of a way?

Tags: openstreetmap

I have a question concerning the data. Are nodes that are tagged as traffic_signals expected to be part of a way that is a k="highway" itself?

```
<node id="12345678" lat="60" lon="10">
    <tag k="highway" v="traffic_signals"/>
</node>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I guess they are supposed to be part of a highway (according to the [wiki page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:highway%3Dtraffic_signals) and to traffic_signals I previously show in OSM).

*"The mapping of traffic signals is an abstraction that the particular junction or way is regulated by traffic lights.
It is not a representation of a particular device.
Thus, because traffic signals can affect routing decisions, it is important that they are attached to the ways to which they apply, and not placed beside the way."* (source : [highway=traffic_signals OSM wiki page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:highway%3Dtraffic_signals))